# Why do my slotchanges revert the assigned nodes after having been correct in the event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, this was a hard question to formulate. I have a custom element representing an icon. I thought it would look nice to have a default image for the icon, so I implemented it using a slot, which works as it should, i.e. the slotted image actually shows on screen.

I need to save the image path in a variable, so I set it first in the constructor (to the default image) and then in a *slotchange* event. The image is set to the path of the slotted image in the event handler, but then in another method, it's back to the default image. I'll post the relevant snippets:

```
constructor {
  this.image = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot[name="icon"] img').src
  // ...
  this.slots = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('slot')
  this.slots.forEach(slot => {
    slot.addEventListener('slotchange', this.handleSlotChanges)
  })
```

Here I set the default image for the icon and add the event listener for the slotchange.

```
  handleSlotChanges (e) {
    if (e.target.name === 'icon') {
      this.image = e.target.assignedNodes()[0].src
      console.log(this.image)
    }
 }
```

Here, I set the image to the slotted content's source, and the log shows that it's the correct source. This happens immediately at creation of the element, as the image is slotted in the HTML file.

In my handler for clicks on the icon, the image is the default image again, as follows:

```
handleClicks (e) {
  // ...
  console.log(this.image)
}
```

I don't set the image anywhere else but in the constructor and the slotchange event handler. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a context mismatch.

when you are setting `slot.addEventListener('slotchange', this.handleSlotChanges)`, when calling this.handleSlotChanges the context will not be the same `this` as what you expect it to be, so `this.image` does not necessarily exist, or at least refer to the image in the class context.

To circumvent the error, you need to bind the function to the context in your constructor, by doing something like this:

```
this.handleSlotChanges = this.handleSlotChanges.bind(this)
```

You can do the same thing when you are passing the function in the addEventListener, but for conciseness it's usually better to do it in the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I have never had this particular problem, because it usually just gives me an exception of some kind (when I want to access a property of some out-of-context variable for example). I guess an arrow function would do, as well.